# How can i select the last value in a particular column in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using this query to fetch all the values from a table where the invoiceNo is distinct.

```
SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```

This is my table structure

[image]

And I would like to access everything from the last row.My current query gives me the first row.Thank you :)

Comment: What about ORDER BY?

Comment: does it give a single row? SELECT * FROM selected_items WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) GROUP BY invoiceNo  order by desc;

Comment: @bub can you give an example.I am very new to programming thanks:)

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan yes it does give  a single row.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thank you for the edit can you help with a solution :)

Comment: try this one, `SELECT * FROM  selected_items WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) GROUP BY invoiceNo ORDER BY custInfo DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: how many distinct invoiceNo you have in your column

Comment: Do you want to get the highest `sum_total` of each `invoiceNo`?

Comment: without any unique column it isn't possible..

Comment: @RajdeepPaul yes I want everything from the last row and it would apparently have the final total.

Comment: can't you store total in different table?

Comment: @user3295583 See my answer.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i tried it did not work for me it returns the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `order by rownum` or `GROUP BY`

```
Select * From (
SELECT t.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM selected_items t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r order by rank DESC
) si GROUP BY si.invoiceNo
```

Comment: in image invoice no,date both are all same

Comment: thats just dummy data.I tried your solution but it still gives me the first row.

Comment: This gives me the first row I want the last row.Please check the updated image

Comment: hey this thing works but it gives me all the rows I want only the row with unique invoiceNo

Comment: hey can I put one more condition in this something like WHERE bill_type LIKE '$invoice'

Comment: yes **WHERE si.bill_type LIKE '%$invoice%' GROUP BY si.invoiceNo** @user3295583

Comment: I tried it gives me error Every derived table must have its own alias when I am testing it i am using a string "Invoice" like -> WHERE si.bill_type LIKE "Invoice" GROUP BY si.invoiceNo;

Comment: Hey can you post a query please I am not able to use a Where clause in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one,

`SELECT * FROM selected_items WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) GROUP BY invoiceNo ORDER BY custInfo DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Yes i did try it it gave me the first row

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ORDER BY`column name so you will get the last entry first

```
SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) GROUP BY invoiceNo ORDER BY invoiceNo DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: you can also give query

Comment: I tried this SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` WHERE invoiceNo IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ( invoiceNo) AS invoiceNo FROM selected_items ) ORDER BY invoiceNo; but this is giving all the rows I want the distinct row.

Comment: use `ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC WHERE id = ***` so you will get the last entry first for particular id. @user3295583 can you please tell me more details about that query..! because that query is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Is it?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT invoiceNo, barcode, description, weight, rate, makingAmt, net_rate, itemTotal, vat 
FROM selected_items 
GROUP BY invoiceNo 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

to get last row there should some fields that contains unique values.

Comment: I tired this but it gives only the invoice numbers

Comment: you have to select remained column names

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the highest `sum_total` of each `invoiceNo` then you can do something like this,

```
SELECT invoiceNo, MAX(sum_total) AS sumTotal
FROM selected_items 
GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```

Comment: This still gives me only the first row